# install puppet5 agent with packer virtualbox vagrant template

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, puppet, packer

I have a very strange behavior when I am creating a vagrant virtualbox packer box. I am using the box with vagrant to test my puppet modules before deploying them to production environment. I would like to use puppet-agent on ubuntu-16.04 for puppet5  server. The output of `PACKER_LOG=1 packer build ubuntu-16.04.json` as you can see in the log file below, but when I log in to the vagrant box I only have `puppet 3.8.x` and `puppet-common` and no trace of `puppet-agent`.

I removed the old box, created a new vagrant to be sure I am using the current box, but unfortunately I couldn't solve this problem.

So either I do `apt-get update && apt-get install puppet-agent` within the box or I install it with vagrant with a shell provisioner, but I would like to manage this with packer.

Here is the relevant part of the log output:

```
==> virtualbox-iso: Provisioning with shell script: scripts/puppet.sh
2018/05/07 05:59:27 ui: ==> virtualbox-iso: Provisioning with shell script: scripts/puppet.sh
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 Opening scripts/puppet.sh for reading
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 [INFO] 181 bytes written for 'uploadData'
2018/05/07 05:59:27 [INFO] 181 bytes written for 'uploadData'
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 [DEBUG] Opening new ssh session
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 [DEBUG] Starting remote scp process:  scp -vt /tmp
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 [DEBUG] Started SCP session, beginning transfers...
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 [DEBUG] scp: Uploading script_8159.sh: perms=C0644 size=181
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 [DEBUG] SCP session complete, closing stdin pipe.
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 [DEBUG] Waiting for SSH session to complete.
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 [DEBUG] scp stderr (length 31): Sink: C0644 181 script_8159.sh
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 [DEBUG] Opening new ssh session
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 [DEBUG] starting remote command: chmod 0755 /tmp/script_8159.sh
2018/05/07 05:59:27 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/05/07 05:59:27 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 [DEBUG] Opening new ssh session
2018/05/07 05:59:27 packer: 2018/05/07 05:59:27 [DEBUG] starting remote command: echo 'vagrant' | PACKER_BUILDER_TYPE='virtualbox-iso' PACKER_BUILD_NAME='virtualbox-iso' PACKER_HTTP_ADDR='10.0.2.2:8421'  sudo -E -S bash '/tmp/script_8159.sh'
2018/05/07 05:59:27 ui:     virtualbox-iso: --2018-05-07 05:59:27--  https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppet5-release-xenial.deb
    virtualbox-iso: --2018-05-07 05:59:27--  https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppet5-release-xenial.deb
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Resolving apt.puppetlabs.com (apt.puppetlabs.com)... 52.85.173.69, 52.85.173.15, 52.85.173.19, ...
    virtualbox-iso: Resolving apt.puppetlabs.com (apt.puppetlabs.com)... 52.85.173.69, 52.85.173.15, 52.85.173.19, ...
    virtualbox-iso: Connecting to apt.puppetlabs.com (apt.puppetlabs.com)|52.85.173.69|:443... connected.
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Connecting to apt.puppetlabs.com (apt.puppetlabs.com)|52.85.173.69|:443... connected.
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
    virtualbox-iso: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
    virtualbox-iso: Length: 6850 (6.7K) [application/x-debian-package]
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Length: 6850 (6.7K) [application/x-debian-package]
    virtualbox-iso: Saving to: ‘puppet5-release-xenial.deb’
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Saving to: ‘puppet5-release-xenial.deb’
    virtualbox-iso:
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso:
    virtualbox-iso:      0K ......                                                100% 29.0M=0s
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso:      0K ......                                                100% 29.0M=0s
    virtualbox-iso:
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso:
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso: 2018-05-07 05:59:28 (29.0 MB/s) - ‘puppet5-release-xenial.deb’ saved [6850/6850]
    virtualbox-iso: 2018-05-07 05:59:28 (29.0 MB/s) - ‘puppet5-release-xenial.deb’ saved [6850/6850]
    virtualbox-iso:
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso:
    virtualbox-iso: Selecting previously unselected package puppet5-release.
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Selecting previously unselected package puppet5-release.
    virtualbox-iso: (Reading database ... 64089 files and directories currently installed.)
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso: (Reading database ... 64089 files and directories currently installed.)
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Preparing to unpack puppet5-release-xenial.deb ...
    virtualbox-iso: Preparing to unpack puppet5-release-xenial.deb ...
    virtualbox-iso: Unpacking puppet5-release (5.0.0-1xenial) ...
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Unpacking puppet5-release (5.0.0-1xenial) ...
2018/05/07 05:59:28 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Setting up puppet5-release (5.0.0-1xenial) ...
    virtualbox-iso: Setting up puppet5-release (5.0.0-1xenial) ...
    virtualbox-iso: Ign:1 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial InRelease
2018/05/07 05:59:29 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Ign:1 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial InRelease
    virtualbox-iso: Get:2 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial Release [57.5 kB]
2018/05/07 05:59:29 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Get:2 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial Release [57.5 kB]
2018/05/07 05:59:29 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
    virtualbox-iso: Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
2018/05/07 05:59:29 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Hit:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
    virtualbox-iso: Hit:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
    virtualbox-iso: Get:5 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial Release.gpg [836 B]
2018/05/07 05:59:29 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Get:5 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial Release.gpg [836 B]
    virtualbox-iso: Hit:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
2018/05/07 05:59:29 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Hit:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
2018/05/07 05:59:29 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Hit:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
    virtualbox-iso: Hit:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
    virtualbox-iso: Get:8 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial/puppet5 amd64 Packages [15.5 kB]
2018/05/07 05:59:30 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Get:8 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial/puppet5 amd64 Packages [15.5 kB]
    virtualbox-iso: Get:9 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial/puppet5 i386 Packages [13.4 kB]
2018/05/07 05:59:30 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Get:9 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial/puppet5 i386 Packages [13.4 kB]
    virtualbox-iso: Get:10 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial/puppet5 all Packages [7,432 B]
2018/05/07 05:59:30 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Get:10 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial/puppet5 all Packages [7,432 B]
2018/05/07 05:59:31 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Fetched 94.6 kB in 1s (51.7 kB/s)
    virtualbox-iso: Fetched 94.6 kB in 1s (51.7 kB/s)
2018/05/07 05:59:33 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Reading package lists...
    virtualbox-iso: Reading package lists...
    virtualbox-iso: Reading package lists...
2018/05/07 05:59:34 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Reading package lists...
2018/05/07 05:59:34 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Building dependency tree...
    virtualbox-iso: Building dependency tree...
2018/05/07 05:59:34 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Reading state information...
    virtualbox-iso: Reading state information...
2018/05/07 05:59:34 ui:     virtualbox-iso: The following NEW packages will be installed:
    virtualbox-iso: The following NEW packages will be installed:
2018/05/07 05:59:34 ui:     virtualbox-iso:   puppet-agent
    virtualbox-iso:   puppet-agent
2018/05/07 05:59:35 ui:     virtualbox-iso: 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
    virtualbox-iso: 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
2018/05/07 05:59:35 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Need to get 17.2 MB of archives.
    virtualbox-iso: Need to get 17.2 MB of archives.
2018/05/07 05:59:35 ui:     virtualbox-iso: After this operation, 96.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    virtualbox-iso: After this operation, 96.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
2018/05/07 05:59:35 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Get:1 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial/puppet5 amd64 puppet-agent amd64 5.5.1-1xenial [17.2 MB]
    virtualbox-iso: Get:1 http://apt.puppetlabs.com xenial/puppet5 amd64 puppet-agent amd64 5.5.1-1xenial [17.2 MB]
    virtualbox-iso: debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
2018/05/07 05:59:42 ui:     virtualbox-iso: debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
2018/05/07 05:59:42 ui:     virtualbox-iso: debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
    virtualbox-iso: debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
    virtualbox-iso: debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
2018/05/07 05:59:42 ui:     virtualbox-iso: debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
2018/05/07 05:59:42 ui:     virtualbox-iso: debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
    virtualbox-iso: debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
    virtualbox-iso: debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
2018/05/07 05:59:42 ui:     virtualbox-iso: debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
2018/05/07 05:59:42 ui:     virtualbox-iso: debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
    virtualbox-iso: debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
2018/05/07 05:59:42 ui:     virtualbox-iso: dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
    virtualbox-iso: dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
2018/05/07 05:59:43 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Fetched 17.2 MB in 7s (2,295 kB/s)
    virtualbox-iso: Fetched 17.2 MB in 7s (2,295 kB/s)
2018/05/07 05:59:43 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Selecting previously unselected package puppet-agent.
    virtualbox-iso: Selecting previously unselected package puppet-agent.
2018/05/07 05:59:43 ui:     virtualbox-iso: (Reading database ... 64094 files and directories currently installed.)
    virtualbox-iso: (Reading database ... 64094 files and directories currently installed.)
2018/05/07 05:59:43 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Preparing to unpack .../puppet-agent_5.5.1-1xenial_amd64.deb ...
    virtualbox-iso: Preparing to unpack .../puppet-agent_5.5.1-1xenial_amd64.deb ...
2018/05/07 05:59:43 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Unpacking puppet-agent (5.5.1-1xenial) ...
    virtualbox-iso: Unpacking puppet-agent (5.5.1-1xenial) ...
    virtualbox-iso: Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
2018/05/07 06:00:19 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
    virtualbox-iso: Setting up puppet-agent (5.5.1-1xenial) ...
2018/05/07 06:00:19 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Setting up puppet-agent (5.5.1-1xenial) ...
2018/05/07 06:00:20 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/puppet.service to /lib/systemd/system/puppet.service.
    virtualbox-iso: Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/puppet.service to /lib/systemd/system/puppet.service.
    virtualbox-iso: Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mcollective.service to /lib/systemd/system/mcollective.service.
2018/05/07 06:00:20 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mcollective.service to /lib/systemd/system/mcollective.service.
    virtualbox-iso: Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/pxp-agent.service to /lib/systemd/system/pxp-agent.service.
2018/05/07 06:00:20 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/pxp-agent.service to /lib/systemd/system/pxp-agent.service.
2018/05/07 06:00:21 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/pxp-agent.service.
    virtualbox-iso: Removed symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/pxp-agent.service.
2018/05/07 06:00:21 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
    virtualbox-iso: Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu10) ...
    virtualbox-iso: Reading package lists...
2018/05/07 06:00:22 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Reading package lists...
    virtualbox-iso: Building dependency tree...
2018/05/07 06:00:22 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Building dependency tree...
2018/05/07 06:00:22 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Reading state information...
    virtualbox-iso: Reading state information...
    virtualbox-iso: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
2018/05/07 06:00:22 ui:     virtualbox-iso: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
2018/05/07 06:00:22 [INFO] 2950 bytes written for 'stdout'
2018/05/07 06:00:22 [INFO] 971 bytes written for 'stderr'
2018/05/07 06:00:22 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/05/07 06:00:22 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/05/07 06:00:22 packer: 2018/05/07 06:00:22 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/05/07 06:00:22 packer: 2018/05/07 06:00:22 [INFO] 2950 bytes written for 'stdout'
2018/05/07 06:00:22 packer: 2018/05/07 06:00:22 [INFO] 971 bytes written for 'stderr'
2018/05/07 06:00:22 packer: 2018/05/07 06:00:22 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/05/07 06:00:22 packer: 2018/05/07 06:00:22 [DEBUG] Opening new ssh session
2018/05/07 06:00:22 packer: 2018/05/07 06:00:22 [DEBUG] starting remote command: rm -f /tmp/script_8159.sh
2018/05/07 06:00:23 packer: 2018/05/07 06:00:23 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/05/07 06:00:23 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/05/07 06:00:23 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2018/05/07 06:00:23 packer: 2018/05/07 06:00:23 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
==> virtualbox-iso: Provisioning with shell script: scripts/cleanup.sh
```

here is my json file:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "vm_name": "ubuntu-16.04",
        "disk_size": "40960",
        "http_directory": "http",
        "hostname": "vagrant",
        "ssh_fullname": "vagrant",
        "ssh_username": "vagrant",
        "ssh_password": "vagrant",
        "ssh_wait_timeout": "10000s",
        "iso_url": "http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.4-server-amd64.iso",
        "iso_checksum_url": "http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/SHA256SUMS",
        "iso_checksum_type": "sha256",
        "preseed" : "preseed.cfg"
    },

    "builders": [{
        "type": "virtualbox-iso",
        "headless": true,
        "boot_wait": "10s",
        "disk_size": "{{user `disk_size`}}",
        "http_directory": "http",
        "guest_os_type": "Ubuntu_64",
        "iso_url": "{{user `iso_url`}}",
        "iso_checksum_url": "{{user `iso_checksum_url`}}",
        "iso_checksum_type": "{{user `iso_checksum_type`}}",
        "ssh_username": "{{user `ssh_username`}}",
        "ssh_password": "{{user `ssh_password`}}",
        "ssh_wait_timeout": "{{user `ssh_wait_timeout`}}",
        "shutdown_command": "echo '{{user `ssh_password`}}' | sudo -S shutdown -P now",
        "guest_additions_path": "VBoxGuestAdditions_{{.Version}}.iso",
        "virtualbox_version_file": ".vbox_version",
        "vboxmanage": [
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--cpus", "2" ],
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--memory", "1024" ],
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--nictype1", "virtio" ],
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--natdnsproxy1", "on" ],
            [ "modifyvm", "{{.Name}}", "--natdnshostresolver1", "on" ]
        ],
       "boot_command": [
            "<enter><wait>",
            "<f6><esc>",
            "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
            "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
            "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
            "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
            "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
            "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
            "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
            "<bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs><bs>",
            "<bs><bs><bs>",
            "/install/vmlinuz noapic ",
            "initrd=/install/initrd.gz ",
            "auto preseed/url=http://{{.HTTPIP}}:{{.HTTPPort}}/preseed.cfg ",
            "auto-install/enable=true ",
            "debconf/frontend=noninteractive<wait> ",
            "debian-installer={{ user `locale` }} auto locale={{ user `locale` }} kbd-chooser/method=de ",
            "fb=false debconf/frontend=noninteractive ",
            "console-setup/ask_detect=false ",
            "keyboard-configuration/modelcode=pc105 ",
            "keyboard-configuration/layout=DE ",
            "keyboard-configuration/variant=DE ",
            "hostname={{user `hostname`}} ",
            "passwd/user-fullname={{ user `ssh_fullname` }} ",
            "passwd/user-password={{ user `ssh_password` }} ",
            "passwd/user-password-again={{ user `ssh_password` }} ",
            "passwd/username={{ user `ssh_username` }} ",
            "-- <wait>",
            "<enter>"
        ]

    }],

    "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "pause_before": "30s",
            "execute_command": "echo '{{ user `ssh_password` }}' | {{.Vars}} sudo -E -S bash '{{.Path}}'",
            "scripts": [
                "scripts/network.sh",
                "scripts/config.sh",
                "scripts/vagrant.sh",
                "scripts/virtualbox.sh",
                "scripts/puppet.sh",
                "scripts/cleanup.sh"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "post-processors": [
        {
            "type": "vagrant",
            "override": {
                "virtualbox": {
                    "output": "ubuntu-16-04-vagrant-vbox.box"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is how I install `puppet-agent` with `scripts/puppet.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash -eux

wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppet5-release-xenial.deb
dpkg -i puppet5-release-xenial.deb
apt-get update
apt-get install puppet-agent -y
gem install r10k
```

If you need the content of the other scripts and the `preseed.cfg` file I'll post them as well.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: The packer template, virtualbox builder output, and the puppet install script all look fine to me, so my guess would be that there is an older puppet being installed somehow that is preceding the puppet from the `puppet-agent` in your path. When you login to your post-provisioned vagrant box, is puppet 5.5.1 installed in `/opt/puppetlabs/bin`? Furthermore, it looks like `gem install r10k` is not occurring during the packer build. Is that true?

Comment: @MattSchuchard I added `gem install r10k` recently and I had the same out put with `r10k`installed. In the post-provisioned box there is no puppet5 in `/opt/puppetlabs/bin`. I am wondering why? I also did a `vagrant up --no-provision`to check whether packer removes the installation afterword some how or the vagrant provisioner. But same issue, no puppet5 is installed.

Comment: @MattSchuchard if you want I can post the content of all other scripts an the Vagrantfile as well.

Comment: Now I removed all the other scripts provisioners except `puppet.sh` with the same result, r10k is installed other wise I have the following packages installed: `puppet`, `puppet-common`, `puppet5-release`, `ruby-puppet-forge`, `ruby-semantic-puppet`. and no trace of `puppet-agent`! I don't get this!!

Comment: now I just kept `apt-get install puppet-agent -y`, the same result. I hope some one can help.

Answer (score 0):

For any one who has similar problem, the solution is quite easy, I don't know why I didn't think about it at first place. Steps to do:

```
#vagrant box list
```

This will list you all boxes are in use by vagrant, due my experience vagrant takes always the first one, unless you specify the box it should use. You can then remove all or uneeded boxes with:

```
#vagrant box remove <box>
```

Thanks @Matt for taking a look into this.

Cheers